# Why are jQuery adding one row per initially loaded row, instead of only one?

Tags: jquery

In the below snippet, I am able to dynamically add more rows, which works perfectly if no rows have been loaded from serverside code, however if I initially have 2 or more rows loaded from serverside code (or hardcoded as in the case below) and I click the "Add row" button, it adds 1 row per initially loaded row .. in the below snippet it has 4 rows initially loaded, therefor it adds 4 new rows instead of only 1.

How can I fix so that it will only add 1 row per click of the button, and add it below all others?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#IT_Email_field_DIV").on("click", ".add_new_frm_field_btn_IT_Email", function() {
    var index = $(".form_field_outer_IT_Email").find(".form_field_outer_row_IT_Email").length + 1;
    $(".form_field_outer_IT_Email").append(`
                      <div class="col-md-12 py-2">
                        <div class="col-md-12 form_field_outer_IT_Email py-0">
                          <div class="row form_field_outer_row_IT_Email">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="IT_Email_field_text[]" id="IT_Email_field_text_${index}" placeholder="Skriv teksten for opgaven" value="" required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                              <select name="IT_Email_field_type[]" id="IT_Email_field_type_${index}" class="form-control form-control-sm select bg-white" required>
                                <option>--Vælg type--</option>
                                <option value="textonly">Tekst</option>
                                <option value="textandfieldfree">Tekst + frittekst felt (maks 50 tegn)</option>
                                <option value="textandfieldnum">Tekst + numerisk felt (maks 10 tegn)</option>
                                <option value="textandfielddynvalue">Tekst + DB value felt (maks 50 tegn)</option>                          
                              </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-2 add_del_btn_outer text-right">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn btn-sm add_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Kopier til nyt felt">
                                <i class="far fa-copy fa-sm"></i>
                              </button>

                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Slet felt">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-sm"></i>
                              </button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>`);

    $(".form_field_outer_IT_Email").find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email:not(:first)").prop("disabled", false);
    $(".form_field_outer_IT_Email").find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email").first().prop("disabled", true);
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });
});


///======Clone method
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#IT_Email_field_DIV").on("click", ".add_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email", function(e) {
    var index = $(e.target).closest(".form_field_outer_IT_Email").find(".form_field_outer_row_IT_Email").length + 1;
    var cloned_el = $(e.target).closest(".form_field_outer_row_IT_Email").clone(true);

    $(e.target).closest(".form_field_outer_IT_Email").last().append(cloned_el).find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email:not(:first)").prop("disabled", false);

    $(e.target).closest(".form_field_outer_IT_Email").find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email").first().prop("disabled", true);


    //change id

    //IT_Email
    $(e.target).closest(".form_field_outer_IT_Email").find(".form_field_outer_row_IT_Email").last().find("input[type='text']").attr("id", "IT_Email_field_text_" + index);
    $(e.target).closest(".form_field_outer_IT_Email").find(".form_field_outer_row_IT_Email").last().find("select").attr("id", "IT_Email_field_type_" + index);


    console.log(cloned_el);
    //count++;
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  //===== delete the form fieed row
  $("#IT_Email_field_DIV").on("click", ".remove_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email", function() {
    $(this).closest(".form_field_outer_row_IT_Email").remove();
    console.log("success");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/3.6.0/mdb.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/3.6.0/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form action="insert_settings_flowcontact_fields.asp" class="needs-validation" name="InsertSettingsFlowcontactFields_IT_Email_Form" id="InsertSettingsFlowcontactFields_IT_Email_Form" method="post">
  <div class="container" id="IT_Email_field_DIV">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 form_sec_outer_task_IT_Email border ">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 py-2">
            <label>&nbsp;Opgave tekst</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 py-2">
            <label> Felt type </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 py-2">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 p-1">
          <div class="col-md-12 form_field_outer_IT_Email p-0">
            <div class="row form_field_outer_row_IT_Email">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="IT_Email_field_text[]" id="IT_Email_field_text_1" placeholder="Skriv teksten for opgaven" value="Første opgave" required />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <select name="IT_Email_field_type[]" id="IT_Email_field_type_1" class="form-control form-control-sm select bg-white" required>
                  <option>--Vælg type--</option>
                  <option value="textonly" SELECTED>Tekst</option>
                  <option value="textandfieldfree">Tekst + frittekst felt (maks 50 tegn)</option>
                  <option value="textandfieldnum">Tekst + numerisk felt (maks 10 tegn)</option>
                  <option value="textandfielddynvalue">Tekst + DB value felt (maks 50 tegn)</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-2 add_del_btn_outer text-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn btn-sm add_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Kopier til nyt felt">
                                <i class="far fa-copy fa-sm"></i>
                              </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Slet felt">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-sm"></i>
                              </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 p-1">
          <div class="col-md-12 form_field_outer_IT_Email p-0">
            <div class="row form_field_outer_row_IT_Email">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="IT_Email_field_text[]" id="IT_Email_field_text_2" placeholder="Skriv teksten for opgaven" value="Anden opgave" required />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <select name="IT_Email_field_type[]" id="IT_Email_field_type_2" class="form-control form-control-sm select bg-white" required>
                  <option>--Vælg type--</option>
                  <option value="textonly">Tekst</option>
                  <option value="textandfieldfree" SELECTED>Tekst + frittekst felt (maks 50 tegn)</option>
                  <option value="textandfieldnum">Tekst + numerisk felt (maks 10 tegn)</option>
                  <option value="textandfielddynvalue">Tekst + DB value felt (maks 50 tegn)</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-2 add_del_btn_outer text-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn btn-sm add_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Kopier til nyt felt">
                                <i class="far fa-copy fa-sm"></i>
                              </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Slet felt">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-sm"></i>
                              </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 p-1">
          <div class="col-md-12 form_field_outer_IT_Email p-0">
            <div class="row form_field_outer_row_IT_Email">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="IT_Email_field_text[]" id="IT_Email_field_text_3" placeholder="Skriv teksten for opgaven" value="Tredie opgave" required />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <select name="IT_Email_field_type[]" id="IT_Email_field_type_3" class="form-control form-control-sm select bg-white" required>
                  <option>--Vælg type--</option>
                  <option value="textonly">Tekst</option>
                  <option value="textandfieldfree">Tekst + frittekst felt (maks 50 tegn)</option>
                  <option value="textandfieldnum" SELECTED>Tekst + numerisk felt (maks 10 tegn)</option>
                  <option value="textandfielddynvalue">Tekst + DB value felt (maks 50 tegn)</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-2 add_del_btn_outer text-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn btn-sm add_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Kopier til nyt felt">
                                <i class="far fa-copy fa-sm"></i>
                              </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Slet felt">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-sm"></i>
                              </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 p-1">
          <div class="col-md-12 form_field_outer_IT_Email p-0">
            <div class="row form_field_outer_row_IT_Email">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="IT_Email_field_text[]" id="IT_Email_field_text_4" placeholder="Skriv teksten for opgaven" value="Fjerde opgave" required />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <select name="IT_Email_field_type[]" id="IT_Email_field_type_4" class="form-control form-control-sm select bg-white" required>
                  <option>--Vælg type--</option>
                  <option value="textonly">Tekst</option>
                  <option value="textandfieldfree">Tekst + frittekst felt (maks 50 tegn)</option>
                  <option value="textandfieldnum">Tekst + numerisk felt (maks 10 tegn)</option>
                  <option value="textandfielddynvalue" SELECTED>Tekst + DB value felt (maks 50 tegn)</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-2 add_del_btn_outer text-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn btn-sm add_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Kopier til nyt felt">
                                <i class="far fa-copy fa-sm"></i>
                              </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Slet felt">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-sm"></i>
                              </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container py-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-rounded py-0 add_new_frm_field_btn_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Tilføj nyt felt"><i class="fas fa-plus add_icon"></i> Add row</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col text-right" align="right">
            <button type="submit" form="InsertSettingsFlowcontactFields_IT_Email_Form" id="InsertSettingsFlowcontactFields_IT_Email_Btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded py-1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Gem ovenstående Opgave Felter"><i class="far fa-save"></i> Gem Opgave Felter</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
<br>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offending line is this one:

```
$(".form_field_outer_IT_Email").append(`
```

... so when you have 4 elements that match the `form_field_outer_IT_Email` selector, the append adds to *each element* in the collection. So with 4, you'll get 4 more.

You can change that to only refer to the *last* entry of the collection for a single reference by doing:

```
$(".form_field_outer_IT_Email").last().append(`
```

Try the example below. Adding the `last()` is the only change, but I did comment-out the console.logs, because the console output starts to obscure the `ADD ROW` button after a few clicks in the runnable code's output area.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //console.log($(".form_field_outer_IT_Email").find(".form_field_outer_row_IT_Email").length)
  $("#IT_Email_field_DIV").on("click", ".add_new_frm_field_btn_IT_Email", function() {
//       console.log("clicked");
    var index = $(".form_field_outer_IT_Email").find(".form_field_outer_row_IT_Email").length + 1;
    $(".form_field_outer_IT_Email").last().append(`
                      <div class="col-md-12 py-2">
                        <div class="col-md-12 form_field_outer_IT_Email py-0">
                          <div class="row form_field_outer_row_IT_Email">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="IT_Email_field_text[]" id="IT_Email_field_text_${index}" placeholder="Skriv teksten for opgaven" value="" required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                              <select name="IT_Email_field_type[]" id="IT_Email_field_type_${index}" class="form-control form-control-sm select bg-white" required>
                                <option>--Vælg type--</option>
                                <option value="textonly">Tekst</option>
                                <option value="textandfieldfree">Tekst + frittekst felt (maks 50 tegn)</option>
                                <option value="textandfieldnum">Tekst + numerisk felt (maks 10 tegn)</option>
                                <option value="textandfielddynvalue">Tekst + DB value felt (maks 50 tegn)</option>                          
                              </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-2 add_del_btn_outer text-right">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn btn-sm add_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Kopier til nyt felt">
                                <i class="far fa-copy fa-sm"></i>
                              </button>

                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Slet felt">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-sm"></i>
                              </button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>`);

    $(".form_field_outer_IT_Email").find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email:not(:first)").prop("disabled", false);
    $(".form_field_outer_IT_Email").find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email").first().prop("disabled", true);
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });
});


///======Clone method
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#IT_Email_field_DIV").on("click", ".add_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email", function(e) {
    var index = $(e.target).closest(".form_field_outer_IT_Email").find(".form_field_outer_row_IT_Email").length + 1;
    var cloned_el = $(e.target).closest(".form_field_outer_row_IT_Email").clone(true);

    $(e.target).closest(".form_field_outer_IT_Email").last().append(cloned_el).find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email:not(:first)").prop("disabled", false);

    $(e.target).closest(".form_field_outer_IT_Email").find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email").first().prop("disabled", true);


    //change id

    //IT_Email
    $(e.target).closest(".form_field_outer_IT_Email").find(".form_field_outer_row_IT_Email").last().find("input[type='text']").attr("id", "IT_Email_field_text_" + index);
    $(e.target).closest(".form_field_outer_IT_Email").find(".form_field_outer_row_IT_Email").last().find("select").attr("id", "IT_Email_field_type_" + index);


    console.log(cloned_el);
    //count++;
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  //===== delete the form fieed row
  $("#IT_Email_field_DIV").on("click", ".remove_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email", function() {
    $(this).closest(".form_field_outer_row_IT_Email").remove();
    console.log("success");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/3.6.0/mdb.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/3.6.0/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form action="insert_settings_flowcontact_fields.asp" class="needs-validation" name="InsertSettingsFlowcontactFields_IT_Email_Form" id="InsertSettingsFlowcontactFields_IT_Email_Form" method="post">
  <div class="container" id="IT_Email_field_DIV">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 form_sec_outer_task_IT_Email border ">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 py-2">
            <label>&nbsp;Opgave tekst</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 py-2">
            <label> Felt type </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 py-2">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 p-1">
          <div class="col-md-12 form_field_outer_IT_Email p-0">
            <div class="row form_field_outer_row_IT_Email">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="IT_Email_field_text[]" id="IT_Email_field_text_1" placeholder="Skriv teksten for opgaven" value="Første opgave" required />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <select name="IT_Email_field_type[]" id="IT_Email_field_type_1" class="form-control form-control-sm select bg-white" required>
                  <option>--Vælg type--</option>
                  <option value="textonly" SELECTED>Tekst</option>
                  <option value="textandfieldfree">Tekst + frittekst felt (maks 50 tegn)</option>
                  <option value="textandfieldnum">Tekst + numerisk felt (maks 10 tegn)</option>
                  <option value="textandfielddynvalue">Tekst + DB value felt (maks 50 tegn)</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-2 add_del_btn_outer text-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn btn-sm add_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Kopier til nyt felt">
                                <i class="far fa-copy fa-sm"></i>
                              </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Slet felt">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-sm"></i>
                              </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 p-1">
          <div class="col-md-12 form_field_outer_IT_Email p-0">
            <div class="row form_field_outer_row_IT_Email">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="IT_Email_field_text[]" id="IT_Email_field_text_2" placeholder="Skriv teksten for opgaven" value="Anden opgave" required />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <select name="IT_Email_field_type[]" id="IT_Email_field_type_2" class="form-control form-control-sm select bg-white" required>
                  <option>--Vælg type--</option>
                  <option value="textonly">Tekst</option>
                  <option value="textandfieldfree" SELECTED>Tekst + frittekst felt (maks 50 tegn)</option>
                  <option value="textandfieldnum">Tekst + numerisk felt (maks 10 tegn)</option>
                  <option value="textandfielddynvalue">Tekst + DB value felt (maks 50 tegn)</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-2 add_del_btn_outer text-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn btn-sm add_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Kopier til nyt felt">
                                <i class="far fa-copy fa-sm"></i>
                              </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Slet felt">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-sm"></i>
                              </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 p-1">
          <div class="col-md-12 form_field_outer_IT_Email p-0">
            <div class="row form_field_outer_row_IT_Email">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="IT_Email_field_text[]" id="IT_Email_field_text_3" placeholder="Skriv teksten for opgaven" value="Tredie opgave" required />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <select name="IT_Email_field_type[]" id="IT_Email_field_type_3" class="form-control form-control-sm select bg-white" required>
                  <option>--Vælg type--</option>
                  <option value="textonly">Tekst</option>
                  <option value="textandfieldfree">Tekst + frittekst felt (maks 50 tegn)</option>
                  <option value="textandfieldnum" SELECTED>Tekst + numerisk felt (maks 10 tegn)</option>
                  <option value="textandfielddynvalue">Tekst + DB value felt (maks 50 tegn)</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-2 add_del_btn_outer text-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn btn-sm add_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Kopier til nyt felt">
                                <i class="far fa-copy fa-sm"></i>
                              </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Slet felt">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-sm"></i>
                              </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 p-1">
          <div class="col-md-12 form_field_outer_IT_Email p-0">
            <div class="row form_field_outer_row_IT_Email">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="IT_Email_field_text[]" id="IT_Email_field_text_4" placeholder="Skriv teksten for opgaven" value="Fjerde opgave" required />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <select name="IT_Email_field_type[]" id="IT_Email_field_type_4" class="form-control form-control-sm select bg-white" required>
                  <option>--Vælg type--</option>
                  <option value="textonly">Tekst</option>
                  <option value="textandfieldfree">Tekst + frittekst felt (maks 50 tegn)</option>
                  <option value="textandfieldnum">Tekst + numerisk felt (maks 10 tegn)</option>
                  <option value="textandfielddynvalue" SELECTED>Tekst + DB value felt (maks 50 tegn)</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-2 add_del_btn_outer text-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn btn-sm add_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Kopier til nyt felt">
                                <i class="far fa-copy fa-sm"></i>
                              </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove_node_btn_frm_field_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Slet felt">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-sm"></i>
                              </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container py-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-rounded py-0 add_new_frm_field_btn_IT_Email" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Tilføj nyt felt"><i class="fas fa-plus add_icon"></i> Add row</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col text-right" align="right">
            <button type="submit" form="InsertSettingsFlowcontactFields_IT_Email_Form" id="InsertSettingsFlowcontactFields_IT_Email_Btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded py-1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Gem ovenstående Opgave Felter"><i class="far fa-save"></i> Gem Opgave Felter</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
<br>
<br>
```